# Dialogo en consola, producto de funciones en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, express

Quisiera saber el motivo que lleva este dialogo, o porque se muestra.

> "(node:16232) DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated, and
>   will be removed in a future version. Use collection.countDocuments or
>   collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead"

Mientras realizaba unas funciones de creaciones de publicaciones para una aplicación web, me encontré con este dialogo en mi terminal, pero hasta ahora no he encontrado el motivo, y si afecta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Warning no viene de NodeJs o Express, viene de MongoDB, es por eso que no lo encontrabas, buscabas donde no era.

Seguramente, estas realizando un 'count()' en alguna de tus funciones de tu código para consultar en la base de datos el numero de elementos y lo que hace el driver de MongoDB es avisarte que en futuras versiones eliminaran o no darán soporte a ese método para dar soporte a 'countDocuments()'. Este cambio se esta aplicando desde la ultima version de MongoDB, la 4.0

Por lo tanto, revisa tu código y sustituye el método para que no te problemas en el futuro.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos